# Removing Sub-Queries to Create a Materialized View

Tags: subquery, materialized-views

I inherited a query that has several sub-queries. The request has been made to run this query from a separate server/database so as to require the use of a dblink to get the data. Here are the constraints and requirements.

1. Because of network issues and other factors, the query takes a long time to run.
2. I need the data in the new database to combine it with other tables and do analysis.
3. The source data does not change often and my need is only to produce periodic reports (once a week on Monday.
4. There are also requests for ad-hoc reports. Running them against the data from Monday is OK so there is no conflict between the report issued on Monday and the ad-hoc report run later in the week.

```
SELECT distinct
    doc.doc_subp_sub_proj JOB_NO,--1
    AWARD_HDR.awh_award_no AWARD_NO,--2
    MSTR_VNDR_LIST.mvl_supp_name SUPPLIER,--3
    DOC.doc_no DOCUMENT_NUMBER,--4
    DOC.doc_desc TITLE,--5
--DOC_SUPP_DOC_NO,
    decode(substr(drh_rseq_rev_no,1,2),'00', substr(drh_rseq_rev_no,3,1), '01', substr(drh_rseq_rev_no,2,2), drh_rseq_rev_no) REV_NO,--6
    decode(DOC_REV_HIST.DRH_SUPP_DOC_REV_NO ,'NA', Null, DOC_REV_HIST.DRH_SUPP_DOC_REV_NO) SUPPLIER_REV_NO,--7
    DOC_REV_HIST.drh_recv_date REV_DATE,--8
    DOC.doc_dst_dctp_cd DISC,--9
    DOC.doc_dst_sub_type_cd DOC_TYPE,--10
    (SELECT rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, srr_sdrl_cd || ';')).extract ('//text()'), ';')
        FROM (SELECT distinct SDRL_RCVD_REQMT.SRR_DRH_DOC_DOC_SEQ_NO, 
                        SDRL_RCVD_REQMT.srr_sdrl_cd
                    FROM SDRL_RCVD_REQMT@DASHBOARD)
                    WHERE SRR_DRH_DOC_DOC_SEQ_NO = DRH_DOC_DOC_SEQ_NO
                    GROUP BY SRR_DRH_DOC_DOC_SEQ_NO) SDRL_CODE, --11
--SDRL_RCVD_REQMT.srr_sdrl_cd,
    decode(SDRL_RCVD_REQMT.srr_das_cd,
'1','1-ACCEPTED',
                             '2','2-ACCEPTED WITH COMMENTS',
                             '3','3-NOT ACCEPTED',
                             '4','4-NOT REVIEWED - ACCEPTED FOR INFO',
                             '5','5-NO COMMENT',
                             '6','6-APPROVED AS CERTIFIED/FINAL',
                             '7','7-WAITING FOR APPROVAL',
                             '8','8-ISSUED FOR INFORMATION',
                             '9','9-PRE-LOAD, NOT RECEIVED') APPROVAL_CODE,--12
    SDRL_RCVD_REQMT.srr_act_date ACTUAL_RECEIVED_DATE,--13
    psr.xdx_thdr_xmtl_no PSR_XMTL_NO,--14
    psr.xdx_thdr_iss_date PSR_ISSUE_DATE,--15
    THD_PSR.THDR_EXP_CO_DATE PSR_DUE_DATE, --16
    psr.XDX_TLI_ACT_RET_DATE PSR_COMPLETE_DATE, --17

    null PROJECTED_SDC_DATE, --18--nvl(psr.XDX_THDR_ACT_CO_DATE,THD_PSR.THDR_EXP_CO_DATE)+2 ,--projected SDC Date

    sdc.xdx_thdr_xmtl_no SDC_XMTL_NO,--19
    sdc.xdx_thdr_iss_date SDC_ISSUE_DATE,--20
    THD_SDC.THDR_EXP_CO_DATE SDC_DUE_DATE, --21
    sdc.XDX_TLI_ACT_RET_DATE SDC_COMPLETE_DATE, --22

    null PROJECTED_SCR_DATE, --23 --decode(AWARD_HDR.awh_award_no,'EL001',NULL,nvl(sdc.XDX_THDR_ACT_CO_DATE, nvl(THD_SDC.THDR_EXP_CO_DATE, nvl(psr.XDX_THDR_ACT_CO_DATE,THD_PSR.THDR_EXP_CO_DATE)+2))+2) ,--projected SCR Date

    SCR.xdx_thdr_xmtl_no SCR_SCA_XMTL_NO,--24
    SCR.xdx_thdr_iss_date SCR_ISSUE,--25
    THD_SCR.THDR_EXP_CO_DATE SCR_EXPECTED,--26
    SCR.XDX_TLI_ACT_RET_DATE SCR_ACTUAL,--27
    nvl(sdc.XDX_THDR_ACT_CO_DATE,THD_SDC.THDR_EXP_CO_DATE)+9 PROJECTED_RTS_DATE,--28--projected RTS Date

    case 
        when rts.xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx = 'RTS' then 'RTS-'||rts.xdx_thdr_xmtl_no
        when rts.xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx ='IAC' then 'IAC-'||rts.xdx_thdr_xmtl_no
        else null 
    end RTS_IAC_XMTL_NO, --29

    rts.xdx_thdr_iss_date RTS_IAC_ISSUED, --30
    SDRL_RCVD_REQMT.srr_next_exp_date NEXT_DUE_DATE --31
    
FROM DOC_REV_HIST@DASHBOARD,
    DOC@DASHBOARD,
    AWARD_HDR@DASHBOARD,
    PROJ_ORG@DASHBOARD,
    MSTR_VNDR_LIST@DASHBOARD,
    SDRL_RCVD_REQMT@DASHBOARD,
    xmtl_doc_xref@DASHBOARD PSR,
    xmtl_doc_xref@DASHBOARD SDC,
    xmtl_doc_xref@DASHBOARD SCR,
    xmtl_doc_xref@DASHBOARD RTS,
    xmtl_doc_xref@DASHBOARD IAC,
    XMTL_HDR@DASHBOARD THD_PSR,
    XMTL_HDR@DASHBOARD THD_SDC,
    XMTL_HDR@DASHBOARD THD_SCR,
    XMTL_HDR@DASHBOARD THD_RTS

WHERE  DOC.doc_doc_seq_no   = DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no
    AND DOC.doc_subp_sub_proj = DOC_REV_HIST.drh_sub_proj
    AND DOC.doc_subp_proj_no = DOC_REV_HIST.drh_proj_no
    AND DOC.DOC_STAT_CD = 'ACTV'
--and DOC.DOC_SUBP_SUB_PROJ like ?
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_seq_no =

        (SELECT  MAX(DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_seq_no)
        FROM   DOC_REV_HIST@DASHBOARD
       WHERE    DOC.doc_doc_seq_no  = DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no
            AND DOC.doc_subp_sub_proj = DOC_REV_HIST.drh_sub_proj
            AND DOC.doc_subp_proj_no = DOC_REV_HIST.drh_proj_no
            AND NVL(DOC_REV_HIST.drh_bk_rev_status,'X') != 'BKREV' )

    AND DOC.doc_awh_award_seq_no  = AWARD_HDR.awh_award_seq_no
    AND AWARD_HDR.awh_supp_porg_seq_no = PROJ_ORG.porg_seq_no
    AND PROJ_ORG.porg_mvl_supp_no = MSTR_VNDR_LIST.mvl_supp_no
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no =  SDRL_RCVD_REQMT.srr_drh_doc_doc_seq_no (+)
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_rev_uid =  SDRL_RCVD_REQMT.srr_drh_rseq_rev_uid (+)
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no = PSR.xdx_tli_drh_doc_seq_no (+)
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_rev_uid  = PSR.xdx_tli_drh_rev_uid (+)
    AND THD_PSR.THDR_SEQ_NO(+)=PSR.XDX_TLI_THDR_SEQ_NO
    AND PSR.xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx (+) = 'PSR'
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no = SDC.xdx_tli_drh_doc_seq_no (+)
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_rev_uid  = SDC.xdx_tli_drh_rev_uid (+)
    AND THD_SDC.THDR_SEQ_NO(+)=SDC.XDX_TLI_THDR_SEQ_NO
    AND SDC.xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx (+) = 'SDC'
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no = SCR.xdx_tli_drh_doc_seq_no (+)
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_rev_uid  = SCR.xdx_tli_drh_rev_uid (+)
    AND THD_SCR.THDR_SEQ_NO(+)=SCR.XDX_TLI_THDR_SEQ_NO
    AND SCR.xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx (+) in ('SCR', 'SCA')
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no = rts.xdx_tli_drh_doc_seq_no (+)
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_rev_uid  = rts.xdx_tli_drh_rev_uid (+)
    AND THD_RTS.THDR_SEQ_NO(+)=RTS.XDX_TLI_THDR_SEQ_NO
    AND rts.xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx (+) in ('RTS','IAC')
/*
and rts.xdx_thdr_xmtl_no = (select max(xdx_thdr_xmtl_no)
                            from xmtl_doc_xref@DASHBOARD
                            where  xdx_tli_drh_doc_seq_no = DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no
                              and  xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx = 'RTS'
                              and  xdx_tli_drh_rev_uid = DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_rev_uid)
*/
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_doc_doc_seq_no = IAC.xdx_tli_drh_doc_seq_no (+)
    AND DOC_REV_HIST.drh_rseq_rev_uid  = IAC.xdx_tli_drh_rev_uid (+)
    AND IAC.xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx (+) = 'IAC'
/*
    AND (decode(substr(drh_rseq_rev_no,1,2),'00',substr(drh_rseq_rev_no,3,1),
                                           '01',substr(drh_rseq_rev_no,2,2),
                                                drh_rseq_rev_no) = '0'
            AND rts.xdx_thdr_tpur_xmtl_pfx IS NULL)
*/
union

SELECT distinct
    snrv.SUBP_SUB_PROJ,
    snrv.AWARD,
    snrv.SUPPLIER,

    null,
    snrv.Tag_no,--5
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,--10
    snrv.SDRL,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,--15
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,--20
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    snrv.EXP

from sdrl_not_rcvd_view@DASHBOARD snrv

order by 1,4
```

I created a view in the new database, but as stated in #1 above, it takes a long time to run. This makes the report run slowly also (I know - if I only need the report once a week, suck it up).

I thought maybe a materialized view would be better and I just synch it when I need it (on Mondays). But I cannot create a materialized view from a query with sub-queries. Any help/suggestions/tips/tricks to do to convert the sub-queries?